# select list title is not showing on mouse hover

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created a Select list and applied jquery UI `selectmenu plugin` like:

```
  <select id="test" title="This is not showing on mouse hover">
  <option..>
  </option>..
  </select>

  $("#test").selectmenu();
```

Now my problem is that the **title** which i gave to my `select list` is not showing on mousehover. Whats the problem ?

Comment: It's working: http://jsfiddle.net/EGksz/

Comment: @Samir Hafez In ur jsfiddle u not applied jqueryui, so when we applied jqueryUI, it will hide the orignal select list and show the selectlist with jqueryui theme and downarrow on its right

Comment: @user1400722 Ahhh. I overlooked that, sorry. Still from the examples I saw I didn't find one that displayed a tooltip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the selectmenu widget does not expose the `title` attribute of the original element.

This may be fixed by the time this widget becomes available in the main jQuery UI tree, but in the meantime you can implement this feature yourself. Try:

```
var $test = $("#test");
$test.selectmenu().selectmenu("widget").attr("title", $test.attr("title"));
```